# Librosa stops matplotlib from working

Tags: python, matplotlib, qt5, librosa

I have this simple python 3 example:

```
import librosa
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# template, Fs = librosa.load('example.wav')

t = np.arange(0, 10)
plt.plot(t)
plt.show()
```

But as soon as I outcomment `librosa.load(...)` the program crashes with this error message:

```
/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt5.py:124: Warning: g_main_context_push_thread_default: assertion 'acquired_context' failed
  qApp = QtWidgets.QApplication([b"matplotlib"])
```

There is still a new window opened for the plot, but it's completely empty.

Comment: No problem here: ```qt 5.6.2, python 3.6.0, librosa 0.5.1, matplotlib 2.0.0.``` Searching for qt in librosa's sources also indicate there is nothing librosa uses (also: ```setup.py```).

Comment: But then what could be the reason pyplot stops working when using librosa?

Comment: As i said: it does not for me. Your setup seems broken. Update/reinstall everything.

Answer (score 1):

Have the exact same problem. Use `scipy.io.wavfile.read(path)` instead.